# UK English: Is "dived" a valid word?

Tags: past-tense, is-it-a-word, transatlantic-differences, irregular

Proofing a manuscript, I found this in the middle of a chase scene:

> Spotting an opening, I dived into it and was horrified to find it was a dead end.

Is “dived” a valid past tense of the verb “dive”? I've always used “dove”, but I'm not certain what the use is in UK English.

Cambridge [shows “dived” as a valid past tense of “dive”](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/dive_1), but which is more common? Do “dove” and “dived” have different shades of meaning, or are they used differently in different contexts?

Comment: Dove, although frequently heard, was considered incorrect and marked wrong by teachers in the Northeastern USA circa 1960. It is now more generally used here, but still sounds wrong to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dive) indicates that ***dived*** is the standard British English past tense of *dive*:

> The past tense **dove** is found chiefly in North American English, where it is used alongside the regular (and earlier) **dived**, with regional variations; in British English **dived** is the standard past tense, **dove** existing only in some dialects. As a past participle, **dove** is relatively rare. (Compare *Merriam-Webster Collegiate Dictionary*; *The American Heritage Dictionary*; *The Cambridge Guide to English Usage*)

Comment: *Dove* is certainly rare as a verb in British English.  I had a mathematics teacher who used it as an affectation, so much so that he sometimes even used it as the present tense; he also wrote *shew* rather than *show*, for much the same reason.

Comment: It needs a broad accent, preferable fairly Northern, to carry it off. A bit like sware, clome, crew, and other strong pasts which are vanishing relics of ME.

Comment: ODO (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dive?q=dived) also refers to *dove* as specifically a US term.

Comment: @Henry I have a tendency to use the past participle _diven_ as an affectation, just to drive home the point.