# What's the past tense of "dive"? Of "spell"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, past-tense, ed-vs-t

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UK English: Is "dived" a valid word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16008/uk-english-is-dived-a-valid-word)
>   [Spelt and Spelled](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/spelt-and-spelled)
>   [“Dreamed” vs. “dreamt”, “leaped” vs. “leapt”, “lighted” vs. “lit”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/dreamed-vs-dreamt-leaped-vs-leapt-lighted-vs-lit)
>   [Evolution of irregular verbs over the last century](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/evolution-of-irregular-verbs-over-the-last-century)
>   [Origin of different past tenses for verbs with the same endings?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/origin-of-different-past-tenses-for-verbs-with-the-same-endings)

What's the difference between 'dived' and 'dove' as the past tense of 'to dive'?
'Spelled' and 'spelt' (*to spell*)? There are others which are similar. Is one form British usage?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the question [evolution of irregular verbs over the last century](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/evolution-of-irregular-verbs-over-the-last-century).

Answer (score 0):

Well,

> Spelled: Past tense of 'spell'
>
> Spelt: An old kind of wheat (Triticum spelta) with bearded ears and spikelets that each contain two narrow grains, not widely grown but favored as a health food.