# Speeded vs. Sped

Tags: word-choice, verbs, is-it-a-word

I think "*speeded*" may have been the appropriate past-tense form for "to speed" in the past, but I wonder if it is still considered the correct form. In spoken English, one usually hears "*sped*" to communicate the same past action.

This might also be the case with "*dived*" and "*dove*," as one rarely hears the former.

Comment: It is still accepted. [General reference](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/speed_3)

Comment: It seems [dived vs dove](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+dived+in%2Che+dove+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is about 50:50. Whereas [sped is far more popular than speeded](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+sped+along%2Che+speeded+along&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: In BrE, *dove* is not correct and *dived* is. I would only use *speeded* as a past-tense of *speed* where the meaning is "travel in excess of the speed limit". If it's simply "travel at speed", then I would prefer *sped*.

Comment: Apparently people only ever write ["he has speeded up"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+has+sped+up%2Che+has+speeded+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), however it's about equal for ["he sped up" vs "he speeded up"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+has+sped+up%2Che+has+speeded+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: @Matt: I think "speed" tends to have a past tense of "speeded" when it's transitive, and "sped" when intransitive. [Compare](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speeded+up+the+process%2Csped+up+the+process%2Csped+up+the+road%2Csped+up+the+hill%2C+speeded+up+the+road%2C+speeded+up+the+hill&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) Ngrams for "sped up the process" and "sped up the hill". This is why "has speeded up" is [more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=has+sped+up%2C+has+speeded+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: In fact, this is more or less what the [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/speed?q=speed) says for British English: use "speeded" for exceeding the speed limit, in the phrasal verb "speeded up", and when transitive; "sped" otherwise. (They don't say what the rule is in AmE. Personally, I'd say "sped up" for intransitive uses of the phrasal verb, but otherwise agree.)

Comment: @PeterShor very interesting.

Answer (score 17):

The usage stats from the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) look as follows:

```
               COCA     BNC

speeded.[v*]    259     149
sped.[v*]      1607     302
```

So *sped* is preferred over *speeded* on both sides of the pond, though considerably more so in the US. The interesting part is this, however:

```
               COCA     BNC

speeded up      178     139
sped up         324       8
```

That is, when it comes to the phrasal verb *to speed up*, the preference is not anywhere as strong in the US, and is outright reversed in the UK.

As to usage over time, the [Corpus of Historical American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/) paints the following picture:

[image: Usage of sped vs. speeded in American English from 1810 to 2000]

<sup>(X axis: year, Y axis: incidences per million words.)</sup>

So *sped* has been preferred over *speeded* for as long as the corpus data goes back.

Generally speaking, irregular verbs tend to become regular over time, rather than the other way round, though the latter is not unheard of, either. However, the more heavily used an irregular verb is, the *less* likely it is to change. (That is true of other irregular words, too—for example, you won't see *childs* superseding *children* any time soon.)

*Dived* vs. *dove* has been discussed [elsewhere on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16008/uk-english-is-dived-a-valid-word). See also these related questions:

- [*Dreamed* vs. *dreamt*, *lighted* vs. *lit*, *leaped* vs. *lept*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2535/300)
- [*Spelled* vs. *spelt*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/spelt-vs-spelled)
- [*Learned* vs. *learnt*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4965/when-do-you-use-learnt-and-when-learned)

Comment: There are other problems. _He sped along the road_ is normal, but not _*He sped, and now he'll pay the price._ _Speeded_ sounds wrong to me in both of these, but the past tense of _speed_ in the automotive legal sense seems indeterminate right now, at least in American English.

Answer (score 6):

The past participles (and past tenses) "speeded" and "sped" are used in different grammatical situations. When "speed" is an intransitive verb, the past tense is almost invariably "sped". When "speed" is a transitive verb, the past tense is usually "speeded" (although "sped" is being increasingly used in this situation).

Consider [the Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sped+down+the+road%2C+speeded+down+the+road&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for "speeded/sped down the road". It's almost always "sped". Now, compare [the Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speeded+the+process%2C+sped+the+process&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) for "speeded/sped the process". It's usually "speeded", although "sped" is now becoming more common.

Comment: Interestingly, in the decade since you posted this answer, "sped the process" has [pulled ahead](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=speeded+the+process%2Csped+the+process&year_start=1920&year_end=2100&smoothing=1&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspeeded%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csped%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cspeeded%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csped%20the%20process%3B%2Cc0) of "speeded the process", confirming your suggestion that "sped" is also becoming increasingly permissible in the transitive form.

Answer (score 1):

"Speeded" and "sped" are both correct inflections of the verb "to speed". They both represent its past tense and past participle form. One thing I would say, though, is that if you choose to use one in a text, use that same variant throughout for consistency.

Comment: It may not always be possible or advisable to "use that same variant throughout for consistency," as they can be effectively used to convey different meanings or a better fit in different contexts. While they are both correct, they are not always exactly synonymous.

Comment: In fact, "sped" is almost always used when "speed" is an intransitive verb, but "speeded" is commonly used when "speed" is a transitive verb. (Similarly, no American would say "I shone my shoes", but Americans usually say "the sun shone" rather than "the sun shined".)

Comment: Why is consistency a virtue?